# Inserting n,...,n+k number in k lines in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

I want to insert [11,12,...,20] in 10 lines of `vscode` editor, somehow I want to simulate `iota` functionality of `golang` in vscode editor, for example let assume we had this lines in vscode editor:

```
line1 xxxxx
line2 xx
line3 xxxxxxxx
.
.
.
line10 xxx
```

I want to add [11,12,...,20] to end of each line with vscode custom snippets!

Desired output will be:

```
line1 xxxxx11
line2 xx12
line3 xxxxxxxx13
.
.
.
line10 xxx20
```

Is it possible with vscode provided snippets or we should develop an extension for this purpose ?
Note that the `init value = 11` and the `count=10` are user defined and not known in the begining.

Comment: It's obviously possible since it can be done using multiple cursors.

Comment: How you want add from 11 to 20, this is example the numbers count and init is unknown ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example how you can append numbers to the ends of the first 10 lines (or to the existing lines if there are fewer).

Excerpt from `package.json`:

```
    "activationEvents": [
        "onCommand:stackoverflow-71294699.appendNumbers"
    ],
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "stackoverflow-71294699.appendNumbers",
                "title": "Append numbers"
            }
        ]
    },
```

extension.ts:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.commands.registerCommand('stackoverflow-71294699.appendNumbers',
            async function () {
                const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
                if (!editor) {
                    return;
                }

                await editor.edit((editBuilder) => {
                    for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
                        if (i >= editor.document.lineCount) {
                            break;
                        }

                        const line = editor.document.lineAt(i);
                        editBuilder.insert(
                            new vscode.Position(i, line.text.length),
                            "" + (10+i)
                        );
                    }
                });
            })
    );
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an extension I wrote you can do math easily on lines/selections/document, etc.  The extension is [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#review-details).

With this keybinding (or it could be a setting):

```
{
  "key": "alt+r",                 // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    
    "find": "(?<=\\w)$",
    "replace": "$${ return ${matchNumber} + 10 }$$",
    "isRegex": true,
    "restrictFind": "selections"
}
```

find: `(?<=\\w)$` matches end of line where there is text

or

find: `$` matches end of all lines - blank or not

replace: `$${ return ${matchNumber} + 10 }$$` will add to the matchNumber - which starts at 1 - and it will go on the end of the line

restrictFind: `selections`  Do this only in any selections

Demo:

[image: add 10 to matchNumber at end of line]

So select as many lines as you want.  And replace `10` in the keybinding with whatever you want to add to each match.